# Play 2.3 scala - Slick with MYSQL issue

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, slick, playframework-2.3

I am currently learning the Play Framework with MYSQL+Slick.

I have tried [this Github sample](https://github.com/tomduhourq/scala-employees) to understand the MYSQL+Slick communication.

- Download the source
- Run the command `activator clean compile run`
- Opened in browser at http://localhost:9000

I am getting the exception below, even though I gave the correct DB credentials and DB.

```
play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [models]]
    at play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:94) ~[play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:743) ~[play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:247) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:238) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:273) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:870) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1659) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
```

Does anybody know how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take the following actions:

1. In mysql, under root user:

   ```
   CREATE USER 'test1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
   CREATE DATABASE emp;
   GRANT ALL ON emp.* TO 'test1'@'localhost';
   ```
2. Ensure you can login as 'test1' and have access to the emp database:

   ```
   mysql -utest1 -pmypass
   use emp
   ```
3. Change credentials in your *conf/application.conf*:

   ```
   db.models.user="test1"
   db.models.pass="mypass"
   ...
   db.default.user="test1"
   db.default.pass="mypass"
   ...
   ```

Then run your application. This should work, at least without connection problems.

Comment: Ahhh... Great. Thanks you so much :) It is working now...  Do you know why the root user is not working?